# Setting up a loop in AsyncTask to retrieve the next iteration of a sequence

Tags: java, android, iterator, android-asynctask, android-gridview

I'm downloading several images and names from a `Collection` and applying them in a `GridView`. I've run into a few problems getting my `AsyncTask` working correctly. I need to return two different values, an image and name, from one url. At the moment, I can correctly download everything and apply the info to my `ImageView` and `TextView`, but my method for doing this only works while I call it in my `Adapter`.

**Problem:**

When I set up my `AsyncTask` to download everything, it only applies the first value of the sequence to the `Views` in my grid. When I log "artistImages", it prints out the other urls of the sequence an enormous number of times, I don't know why this happens, but none of the data from the urls is actually applied in my `Adapter`.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried setting up a loop in `doInBackground()` to run through my `Iterator` *n* times.

I've tried using a `Boolean` to stop my iterator before it applies the data from the first set in the sequence to all my `Views`.

I've tried setting my up `Adapter` in my `AsyncTask`.

I've tried setting my a new `AsyncTask` in my `Adapter`, rather than creating a new class.

I've tried setting my `ImageView` in `onPostExecute()` and in my `Adapter`.

I've tried using different parameters in my `AsyncTask`.

I've tried setting up a `AsyncTask` for my `Views`, so that my `Iterator` can run functionally and the images and name are applied asynchronously.

I've done a lot of research on stopping the loop or `AsyncTask` at a certain point, setting up `AsyncTaks` in a `GridView` or with an `Adapter`, and a lot more reading on `Threads`, `Handlers`, and `AsyncTask` in general.

All of these attempts either result in only the first set of the sequence being used or nothing being downloaded and applied at all. So, I'm having a pretty difficult time using my `Iterator` in my `AsyncTask`.

This is the code I'm using to download the images and names. This works as long as I'm using it within the `getView` method my `Adapter`.

**Used to download images and names:**

```
i++;
artistImage = Artist.getSimilar("Bon Iver", i, key);
new ArrayList<Artist>();
itr = artistImage.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Artist temp = itr.next();
    artistImages = ((ImageHolder) temp).getImageURL(ImageSize.MEGA);
    artistName = ((MusicEntry) temp).getName();
}
```

**Just to show what everything is:**

```
private Iterator<Artist> itr;
private Collection<Artist> artistImage;
private String artistImages = null;
private String artistName = null;
private int i = 0;
```

**AsyncTask:** I'm calling this in `getView` of my `Adapter`. `new loadImages().execute()`

```
public class loadImages extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                artistImage = Artist.getSimilar("Bon Iver", i, key);
                new ArrayList<Artist>();
                itr = artistImage.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Artist temp = itr.next();
                    artistImages = ((ImageHolder) temp)
                            .getImageURL(ImageSize.MEGA);
                    artistName = ((MusicEntry) temp).getName();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("images", e.getMessage());
        }
        return artistImages;
    }
}
```

So, I'm unsure how to set this up correctly and it's time to ask for some help. After my fair share of failed attempts, on the plus side I've learned a lot about making my app more efficient. I'd appreciate some advice.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the values you are iterating over. How is it supposed to work? You assign `artistImages` lots of times, but only return the last value.

Comment: Hence my question. I don't know why using that method to download the images and names won't work in my `AsyncTask`, but will if I use it directly in my `Adapter`. I don't know how to use `AsyncTask` correctly, in this case.

Comment: What are you doing with `artistImages` and `artistName`? Are you supposed to be adding them to the grid view? If so, you're just not doing it. The code is not there. You just assign them over and over again. It should not have worked inside the adapter either.

Comment: I'm calling `setText()` with `artistName` and using using a library that basically helps me decode the `InputStream` of `artistImage`. I don't know what else to say. It works correctly 100% of the time as long as I'm calling everything within my `Adapter`.

Comment: @aneal, @ABentSpoon is right. This code: `artistImages = ((ImageHolder) temp)
                            .getImageURL(ImageSize.MEGA);
                    artistName = ((MusicEntry) temp).getName();` doesn't do anything. What did you write these three liens for?

Comment: They do something. These are the methods you call to get the url of the images for similar artists and name. [Last.fm java library.](http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-java/) They aren't just random things I'm pulling out of thin air. I think the problem I'm having isn't the methods I'm using, it's that I don't know how to use AsyncTask with an Iterator. If they didn't do anything, like you both say, then they wouldn't work. Like I've said, they do work as long as I"m using them within my Adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the code that should give you fair idea on how you should deal with adapter and async task. Like @ABentSpoon and @Fixpoint, I'm also confused how you are using these variables. But I'm ignoring these and focusing on ideally how the code structure should be for your case.

Adapter.getView() method is called once for each cell or item in the grid. If your going to run async task from within getView() it will be executed for each item. I think that is why you are seeing enormouse amount of prints.

```
public class ArtistImage {
    public String image;
    public String name;
}

public class LoadImages extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<ArtistImage>> {
    private List<ArtistImage> artistImages = new ArrayList<ArtistImage>();
    private ArtistAdapter artistAdapter;

    public LoadImages(ArtistAdapter adapter) {
        artistAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ArtistImage> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {           
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                Collection<Artist> artistImage = Artist.getSimilar("Bon Iver", i, key);
                Iterator<Artist> itr = artistImage.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Artist temp = itr.next();
                    ArtistImage ai = new ArtistImage();
                    ai.image = ((ImageHolder) temp).getImageURL(ImageSize.MEGA);
                    ai.name = ((MusicEntry) temp).getName();
                    artistImages.add(ai);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("images", e.getMessage());
        }

        return artistImages;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ArtistImage> result) {
        artistAdapter.setArtistImages(result);
    }
}


public class ArtistAdapter extends ... {
    private List<ArtistImage> artistImages = new ArrayList<ArtistImage>();

    public void setArtistImages(List<ArtistImage> images) {
        this.artistImages = images;
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ArtistImage image = artistImages.get(position);
        // render stuff here
    }
}
```

In your activity, either onCreate or some event:

```
ArtistAdapter aa = new ArtistAdapter();
LoadImages loadImages = new LoadImages(aa);
loadImages.execute();
```

Comment: This is actually super helpful. I definitely understand everything a little more. `ArtistImage image = artistImages.get(position)` throws a n `IndexOutOfBoundsExcpetion` and I'll have to figure out why, but that is all really useful. Thank you.